# What is the nomenclature for idpost Fb?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Where can I find the nomenclature for Fb id post and comment? Why sometimes it has a _ id? In what cases does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can (partially) refer to the FQL table docs for this:

- Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/#columns (Field "id")
- Post: If the Post_ID contains a underscore, normally the first part is the User_ID of the User who posted the object with the second part's ID.

Comment: You should be treating IDs as opaque, if you're assuming that there's a pattern there your app could break if it ever changes

Comment: You may be right with your comment, but there are no details in the question how this info should be used. The question was about the "nomenclature"...